# Rails 2.3.8: Showing a button as as hyperlink

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, put

I'm relatively new to Ruby on Rails. As of now have this working code in one of the views in my Rails 2.3.8 application:

```
 <% form_for(@configuration) do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_field :parameter_a %>
 <%= f.text_field :parameter_b %>
 <%= button_to( "Apply", {} , { :method => "put" } ) %>
 <% end %>
```

As expected pressing the "Apply" button calls `update` in the controller. Now I would like to have the button shown in a hyperlink style and I'm looking for most efficient way to do this.

Maybe there are other ways, but I didn't figure out how to use `link_to` correctly. It never passed the updated values in the PUT request. If you'd recommend `link_to`, could you please provide some hints how to do it. This is the non-working code:

```
<%= link_to( "Apply", configuration_path( @configuration ), { :method => "put" } ) %>
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is by using the html `button` element and some css. I much prefer this technique since it requires no JS. This can also be done on input tags, using either their type or their class to select them, but buttons are nicer ;)

As an aside, you shouldn't be using `button_to` there. Rails' `button_to` tag is supposed to be used outside a form (because it builds it's own form), you should use `f.submit`. It will generate an input with a type of submit. Or, you could use a button submit.

Back to using a `button` tag, I prefer to create a helper:

```
def submit_button(text)
  content_tag :button, text, :type => :submit
end
```

Then, once you've used that, you can make the button look like a link with this css:

```
button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #1f44ff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

You may need to use JS to get the hover state to work in some browsers, but it's still better than using JS for the submission of the form.

Answer (score 0):

The only way (I know of) to submit a form with link in HTML is by making the link trigger some javascript.

This is pseudo code, replace the actual form submission with the javascript library of your choice:

```
<% form_for(@configuration), :id=>'my_form' do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :parameter_a %>
  <%= f.text_field :parameter_b %>
  <%= link_to_function "Apply", "$('my_form').submit()" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, let me check.